# calculate the range and quartiles

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

| [![Marks | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| 0-10 | 5 |
| 10-20 | 13 |
| 20-30 | 20 |
| 30-40 | 32 |
| 40-50 | 60 |

I want to calculate quartile and range of above data please help using python  also represent suitable plot using Matplotlib
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0cNf.png

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). SO is not a place to ask others simply to solve entire coding problems for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this formula](https://allthingsstatistics.com/miscellaneous/quartiles-grouped-data-calculation/#:%7E:text=Find%20the%20value%20of%20N,than%20(iN%2F4).) to solve it

```py
# Formula for finding "i"th quartile:
# Q_i = L + h/f (i*N/4 - c.f)


data = {
    (0, 10): 5,
    (10, 20): 13,
    (20, 30): 20,
    (30, 40): 32,
    (40, 50): 60
}


i = 1   # Quartile you want to find

x = (i * sum(data.values())) / 4   # Precalculate i*N/4

c_f = [sum(list(data.values())[:n]) for n in range(1, len(data) + 1)]   # Cumulative frequencies

# Calculate class which the quartile is in
# (L = lower, u = upper, f = frequency, c = cumulative frequency)
for ((L, u), f), c in zip(data.items(), c_f):
    if c >= x:
        break

h = u - L   # Class size
C_f = c - f

Q_i = L + ((h/f) * (x - C_f))
print('Quartile ', i, ': ', Q_i, sep='')
```

Output: `Quartile 1: 27.25`